# I want to confirm the bug of AS3, HTTPservice

Tags: php, actionscript-3, http

## Question

### about HTTPservice.send()

HTTPservice.send() didn't work when request object has Object in the Array.(my coworker reported PHP's server side log show that POST query is wrong, thus I suspected transformation mistake from Object to POST Parameter)

### sample code

```
saveService = new HTTPService();
var action_url:String = "save_score.json";
saveService.url =api_url; 
saveService.method = "POST";
saveService.resultFormat = mx.rpc.http.HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;
saveService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, saveResult); 
saveService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, saveFault);
var params:Object = new Object();;
params.score_id = SCORE_ID;
params.boxes = new Array();

var boxArray:Array = [
{
    "column" : 1,
    "row" : 1,
    "symbol" : "GUItest",
    "explanation" : "GUItest",
    "pronunciation" : "GUItest",
    "subsymbols" : [
        {
            "division" : 1,
            "subsymbol_id" : 1
        }
    ]
}]

params.boxes = boxArray;
saveService.send();
```

I evade this issue by using URLRequest, URLVariables, URLLoader, but I hope your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when POSTing an object or building an object from HTTP reply data, have a look at [HTTPService's serializationFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#serializationFilter).

You provide an adapter, which should be able to do the actual object/flat and flat/object conversions.

Comment: Oh, serializationFilter...  Thanks, this is my fault.  Try to do it.